# CBCentralManager state is Off, even-though the bluetooth is ON

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I am trying to check whether the bluetooth is turned on/off with the following code. But it returns CBManagerStatePoweredOff even-though the bluetooth is already on. I checked it in iPhone6s and iOS version 11.2.5(15D60). If i restart bluetooth manually on the settings, It returns CBManagerStatePoweredOn.

```
- (void)detectBluetooth
{
  if(!bluetoothManager)
  {
    // Put on main queue so we can call UIAlertView from delegate callbacks.
    //    NSDictionary *options = @{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: @NO};
    //    bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:options];
    bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [bluetoothManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
  }

  [self centralManagerDidUpdateState:bluetoothManager]; // Show initial state
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
  NSString *stateString = nil;
  switch(central.state)
  {
    case CBManagerStateResetting:
      stateString = @"The connection with the system service was momentarily lost, update imminent.";
      break;
    case CBManagerStateUnsupported:
      stateString = @"The platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy.";
      break;
    case CBManagerStateUnauthorized:
      stateString = @"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy.";
      break;
    case CBManagerStatePoweredOff:
      stateString = @"Bluetooth is currently powered off.";
      break;
    case CBManagerStatePoweredOn:
      [self goToSearchDevices];
      break;
    default: stateString = @"State unknown, update imminent."; break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Facing the same problem time to time...

Comment: Any Fixes for this?